# Should i dispose IScheduler.Schedule subscription mannualy to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

In my project i have to call `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() => ...)`
Should I dispose subscription mannualy by adding `DisposeWith(DisposableOnDestroy)` or it automatically called by destructor?

I have read ReactiveUI recomendations, but did not find answer

```
RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() => this.RaisePropertyChanged(statisticName))
```

Comment: Usually if you're having to use the MainThreadScheduler like that to set a property you might want to re-evaluate that approach. Most observables offer a IScheduler option via the ObserveOn option, and so do ReactiveCommand's which can allow you to dispatch onto the main thread the main result by using Subscribe(). I would evaluate what you are doing in this scenario.

Comment: Properties in my app can be changed not only in Main Thread. But i want to bind interface elements to theirs by OneWayBind extension method. This method does not have Scheduler parameter. Therefore i should generate RaisePropertyChanged by myself.

Comment: You can use `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Property).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).BindTo(ViewModel, vm => vm.VmProperty);`

Comment: It is not convinient to change OneWayBind to BindTo in a lot of places in code.

Comment: Maybe, but it'd be way more performant and less buggy then the scheduler solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, only Dispose if you want to cancel a queued operation early. Also, what you're trying to do with RaisePropertyChanged here will eventually make your app extremely slow once it gets bigger.

Comment: "No, only Dispose if you want to cancel a queued operation early" - OK. But if subscription is not disposed by Reactive library. Or library do it obligatory and subscription object will be collected by GC?

Comment: It’s disposed of automatically by Rx when it completes, so yes, it will be eligible for garbage collection automatically.

Comment: When Observables complete, they are automatically cleaned up. If a Subscription is infinite (i.e. a Command), the lifetime of that subscription is tied to the object you subscribed to. If a ViewModel goes away and the only thing subscribing to its members is itself, the whole thing goes away