# Disposing IScheduler.Scheduler results

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I want to automatically dispose RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule subscription. I create CompositeDisposable disposable and dispose it in Schedule method (see code below).
Is it best practice or can cause memory leaks or blocking GC collection?

```
private async Task RunAndWaitInMainThread(Action action)
{
    AsyncSubject<Unit> waiter = new AsyncSubject<Unit>();
    CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() =>
    {
        action();
        waiter.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        waiter.OnCompleted();
        disposable.Clear(); // dispose subscription
    })
    .DisposeWith(disposable);

    await waiter; 
}
```

Comment: A couple people already gave answers to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026600/should-i-dispose-ischeduler-schedule-subscription-mannualy-to-avoid-memory-leaks